# How can I show song duration and circular seekbar

Tags: android, audio-player, android-music-player

Im beginner in Android and I'm create one music app but I need to show song duration and circular seekbar on my app

Comment: Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

I have used the circular seekbar please see the example....

You have to implement this in your Gradle dependencies

```
 implementation 'me.tankery.lib:circularSeekBar:1.1.7'
```

Then implement it in your xml try it in your own...

```
<me.tankery.lib.circularseekbar.CircularSeekBar
    android:id="@+id/circularSeekBar"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:cs_circle_color="#0000ff"
    app:cs_circle_progress_color="#ff0000"
    app:cs_circle_stroke_width="4dp"
    app:cs_pointer_color="#ff0000"
    app:cs_pointer_stroke_width="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

In your Activity

```
CircularSeekBar seekBar=findViewById(R.id.circularSeekbar);
```

For setting the seekbar with media player...put the setProgress code in handler to update the seekbar every second

```
            seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
            seekBar.setProgress(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());

seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, float 
progress, boolean fromUser) {

                     int h = Math.round(progress);
 //In the above line we are converting the float value into int because 
// media player required int value and seekbar library gives progress in float
                    if (mediaPlayer != null && fromUser) {
                        mediaPlayer.seekTo(h);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                }
            });
```

I am not providing image but it is working fine

Comment: it is giving me the exact view

Comment: but  myMediaPlayer.seekTo(seekBar.getProgress()); this method is not work

Comment: because you use invalid method try seekbar change listener to set your media player at specific position with seekbar just see the edited answer and don't forget to upmark this if it help you